# How to prove the inequality $a_1^{a_1}a_2^{a_2}\cdots a_n^{a_n} > \left(\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{n}\right)^{a_1+\dots+a_n}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are all unequal positive quantities, then prove that:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n a_i^{a_i} > \left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{n}\right)^{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}$$

No other conditions are given.

I tried to solve it using logarithms, but I could not understand how can I prove $${a_1\log a_1}+{a_2 \log a_2}+\dots+{a_n\log a_n} > {(a_1+\dots +a_n)} 
\left(\log(a+\dots+a_n)-\log(n)\right)$$

And please tell me, is there any standard method to solve this kind of problems?

Comment: In my book it is given like this, by the way the name of the book is "Higher Algebra" by "Hall & Knight".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $n$ positive elements $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be the variables and $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are their respective frequencies. Then GM of this data is
$$GM=\left(a_1^{a_1}a_2^{a_2}\cdots a_n^{a_n}\right)^{\left(\frac{1}{a_1+\dots+a_n}\right)}$$ and
the corresponding $HM$ is
$$HM=\frac{a_1+a_1+a_3+\dots+a_n}{\frac{a_1}{a_1}+\frac{a_2}{a_2}+\frac{a_3}{a_3}+\dots+\frac{a_n}{a_n}}=\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots+a_n}{n}.$$
The required result follows from the fact that wieghted GM $\ge$ weighted HM.
$$\mbox{weighted HM}=\frac{f_1+f_2+f_3+\dots+f_n}{\frac{f_1}{x_1}+\frac{f_2}{x_2}+\frac{f_3}{x_3}+\dots+\frac{f_n}{x_n}}$$ and $$\mbox{weighted} ~ GM=\left({x_1}^{f_1} {x_2}^{f_2} {x_3}^{f_3}\cdots{x_n}^{f_n}\right)^{\frac{1}{f_1+f_2+f_3+\dots+f_n}}.$$

Comment: Can you please tell me, how do you get that HM?

Comment: Yes, $HM=\frac{f_1+f_2+f_3+....+f_n}{\frac{f_1}{x_1}+\frac{f_3}{x_3}+...+\frac{f_n}{x_n}}.$

Answer (score 2):

The hint:

Write it so:
$$\frac{a_1\ln{a_1}+\dots+a_n\ln{a_n}}{n}\geq\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{n}\ln\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{n}$$

and use  Jensen for $f(x)=x\ln{x}.$

Comment: I don't know the Jensen inequality, and it is also not given in my book. So is there any other method than that.

Comment: @bigolo Do you know derivatives?

Comment: yes, I know differentiation.

Comment: @bigolo If so calculate please $(x\ln{x})''.$ What did you get?

Comment: the result is $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Which says $f''(x)>0$ and we know that $f'$ increases. Now draw the graph of $f$ and put on the graph points $(a,f(a))$, $(b,f(b))$,...$(k,f(k))$. I think, now the equality, which I wrote should be obvious.

Comment: I think there will be no equality, because $a \neq b \neq c \neq .... \neq k$

Comment: Yes, of course. Now it's clear? The essence of the inequality, which I wrote that the center of a gravity of these points is placed above the point $\left(\frac{a+...+k}{n},f\left(\frac{a+...+k}{n}\right)\right).$

Comment: I have understood it, but I was expecting an elementary algebraic method to solve this question. But, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @bigolo I think it does not exist. By the way, I see another solution, but we need to use derivatives again.

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

Easy to see that our inequality does not depend on the substitution $a_1\rightarrow ta_1,\dots,a_n\rightarrow ta_n$, where $t>0$.

Thus, we can assume that $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n=n$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}a\ln{a}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a\ln{a}-a+1)\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$a\ln{a}-a+1\geq0$$ for all $a>0.$